# linter err113: do not define dynamic errors, use wrapped static errors instead

Tags: go

I am using `err113` as part of `golangci-lint`.

It  is complaining about ...

```
foo_test.go:55:61: err113: do not define dynamic errors, use wrapped static errors instead: "errors.New(\"repo gave err\")" (goerr113)
        repoMock.EXPECT().Save(gomock.Eq(&foooBarBar)).Return(nil, errors.New("repo gave err")),
                                                                  ^

foo_test.go:22:42: err113: do not define dynamic errors, use wrapped static errors instead: "errors.New(\"oops\")" (goerr113)
    repoMock.EXPECT().FindAll().Return(nil, errors.New("oops"))
                                            ^
```

What is best way to fix this ?

Quoting https://github.com/Djarvur/go-err113

> Also, any call of errors.New() and fmt.Errorf() methods are reported
>   except the calls used to initialise package-level variables and the
>   fmt.Errorf() calls wrapping the other errors.

I am trying to get a idiomatic example for this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Declare a package-level variables as suggested:

```
 var repoGaveErr = errors.New("repo gave err")

 func someFunc() {
    repoMock.EXPECT().Save(gomock.Eq(&foooBarBar)).Return(nil, repoGaveErr)
 }
```

Every call to errors.New allocates a new unique error value. The application creates a single value representing the error by declaring the package-level variable.

There are two motivations for the single value:

- The application can compare values for equality to check for a specific error condition.
- Reduce memory allocations (although probably not a big deal in practice)

The value [io.EOF](https://godoc.org/io#EOF) is a canonical example.

Comment: The downside to reducing memory allocations is that you are guarateed to do at least one memory allocation of that error during program startup.

Also I assume errors are an exception no the rule, in which case the allocation is an exception.

Answer (score 15):

Since **GO 1.13** you can define a new error type, wrap it and use it.
for example, if you want to return an "operation not permitted" + the operation.
you need to implement something like

```
var OperationNotPermit = errors.New("operation not permitted")

func OperationNotFoundError(op string) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("OperationNotPermit %w : %s", OperationNotPermit, op)
}
```

then in your code, when you want to return the error,

```
return nil, OperationNotFoundError(Op)
```

**Let's back to question case:**

first, define the custom error and the wapper

```
var repoError = errors.New("repositoryError")

func RepositoryError(msg string) error {
    return fmt.Errorf("%w: %s", repoError,msg)
}
```

then in your code,

```
repoMock.EXPECT().Save(gomock.Eq(&foooBarBar)).Return(nil, RepositoryError("YOUR CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGE"))
```

Comment: Just wonder the merit of wrapping errors with functions like these...could anyone kindly explain it to me?

Comment: In this case, there is none, unless you want to compare RepositoryError (which you could also just do by defining a function scoped variable). See https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors for more info

Comment: yes, what is the difference between `errors.New("meh: "+err.Error())` and `fmt.Errorf("meh: %s", err.Error())` first should work faster, why ever use fmt?

Comment: Use `fmt.Errorf` to be able to use `%w`, which wraps the original error, using `errors.New("meh: "+err.Error())` would lose the original error type.

Answer (score 5):

Since it hasn't been said before, you **probably don't need to define package level errors for tests**. Given the idea is to wrap errors so they can be compared and unwrapped in the caller, returning a dynamic error in a test is fine as long as the purposes of your test are served.